# Windows task scheduler does not run my powershellscript completely

Tags: windows, powershell, server, scheduled-tasks, gpo

I have 3 windows 2016 servers which are all in a domain.
I am trying to push a powershell script which installs a specific program on my servers.

The script works locally (I ran it on one server) but when it gets pushed with GPO scheduled task it does not execute everything?
This is the script.

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path 'C:\Temp' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {

    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path 'C:\Temp' -Force

}
if (Test-Path -Path $SensorShare) {

    Copy-Item -Path $SensorShare -Destination $SensorLocal -Force

}
if (!(Get-Service -Name 'Service' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\pathto\executable" -ArgumentList '/install /quiet /norestart GROUPING_TAGS="TAG" CID=IDHere' -WindowStyle Hidden

}
```

The first part makes a folder in the C drive and basically pastes the exe there for later installing it.
This happens perfectly, the temp folder is available on all servers but then it does not install the program.

Without scheduler the program works fine.

[Scheduledtaskgeneral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZYMm.png)

[Action of scheduled task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvGOi.png)

I don't know what I am doing wrong, these pictures are how I configured the scheduled task through gpo.

Can anybody help on this issue?

Comment: Please tell us what variables `$SensorShare` and `$SensorLocal` contain

Comment: Those variables are just paths. The share has the executable in a networkshare. The executable is copied from the share to a place on the local C disk. Maybe this step is not really necessary, now that I think about it. Nevertheless this part of the script works fine.

Comment: So `$SensorLocal` is `C:\Temp`?

Comment: Yes exactly, I think the servers get prompted with a UAC prompt and it automatically presses no. I am not sure but I think this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Start-Process -Verb RunAs ...` to start the installer process as admin. Otherwise you start it as simple user in another process.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the user account you are using for running this script have the necessary privileges to install a program.
2. Try to run this script with administrator privileges by Right clicking this file and then selecting "Run as Administrator" option.

Comment: The scheduled task is performed with the SYSTEM priviliges. This one has full control over the script.